# Material 2 - md-sidenav not opening from right to left

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want the side navigation to open from right to left. I used the align property and set it to "rtl" but it is not working.

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>
  <md-sidenav align="rtl" #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Link: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align` takes 'start' or 'end' as values. Change your html t0:

> ```
> <md-sidenav align="end" #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
>     Jolly good!
> </md-sidenav>
> ```

[**PLUNKER DEMO HERE**](https://plnkr.co/edit/IiHeHNXN15STcILMsYsC?p=preview)